# Why are SVG objects always drawn later?

Tags: html, svg

In my HTML5 page, I'm incorporating SVG with fallback the following way. Behind is a background :

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="simpleParallelogram.svg" width="284" height="460">
    <img src="simpleParallelogram_fallback.jpg" width="284" height="460">
</object>   

<img src="background.jpg">
```

No matter where I put the SVG object in the page (which is a very simple parallelogram), I always experience a delay in its displaying. The background is drawn, then the SVG pops up, resulting in a disgraceful stuttering load.

Any ideas why and how I can prevent it?

Comment: If it's a very simple parallelogram, why don't you just embed the SVG data directly inside your HTML file instead of getting the client to request another remote resource after the HTML has loaded?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage That's a clever suggestion that solves the flickering problem. However I don't do it because I need a SVG fallback which doesn't require JS, and _idealy_ doesn't load both SVG and fallback. Is there no way to prevent that flickering while the SVG is loaded externally ?

Comment: No need to make "why" and "how" bold - people *should* read your question before posting answers.

Comment: It's hard to make concrete suggestions without seeing what you're actually doing, but [have you tried any of the SVG fallback techniques discussed on this page?](http://css-tricks.com/svg-fallbacks/) It would probably help if you could embed a snippet in your question or post an example of the problem at jsfiddle.com

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Thanks for the tip ! Just arrived so I still have to get familiar to stackoverflow's usages.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I indeed tried all the SVG fallback techniques on this page. Regarding my problem, only the _CSS background technique_ and the _Inline SVG technique_ prevents the SVG from flickering. It seems there is NO way to prevent flickering when the SVG is loaded externally by HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG object are not always drawn later. It depends on the way they are embbed in the HTML page. If you want an instant drawing of the SVG and a fallback without javascript, you have to use either :

### The CSS background technique

The SVG will be referenced in the CSS. Because CSS is loaded in the *head* section, it will draw the SVG as it appears in the HTML code.

```
.my-element {
    background-image: url(fallback.png);
    background-image: 
    linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
    url(image.svg);
}
```

[More details on how to use this technique](http://pauginer.com/post/36614680636/invisible-gradient-technique)

### The inline SVG with *foreignObject* technique

Because it's inline, the SVG will be drawn as it appears in the HTML code.

```
<svg>
    <switch>
        <g>
           /* Here the SVG code */
        </g>
        <foreignObject>
            /* Here the image fallback */
        </foreignObject>
    </switch>
</svg>
```

[More details on how to use this technique](http://davidensinger.com/2013/04/inline-svg-with-png-fallback/)

All the others SVG inclusion techniques, will result in a delay in the displaying of the SVG.