# Angular2 project keeps refreshing when sanitized property changes

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

```
this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl( svg );
```

I need to sanitize this svg path so that Angular2 doens't give me any errors. I also change the path when i hover it. I do this with (mouseenter) and (mouseleave).

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="setTool('text')" (mouseenter)="changeTextSvg('assets/svg/cv_text_white.svg')" (mouseleave)="changeTextSvg('assets/svg/cv_text.svg')">
```

In the button i have a  element that contains a data attributed that is binded to the correct property:

```
 <object type="image/svg+xml" [data]="safeTextSvg" class="svg"></object>
```

Every time I enter or leave i can see the browser refreshing real quick. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: AFAIR this is browser behavior with the `<object>` element.

Comment: Thanks, when testing in Firefox it's completely unusable. Guess i have to find an other solution.

Comment: You could try a wrapper element where you add the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event bindings andswitch between between two objects like `<object *ngIf="isMouseOver" ...><object *ngIf="!isMouseOver" ...>`

Comment: That might be a better idea, thanks!

Comment: This gives the same effect. But thanks for the response though

Comment: Using `[hidden]="isMouseOver"` would probably be worth a try. `*ngIf` is adding/removing elements, while `hidden` only hides/shows them.

Comment: This is working much better. Still have to work on the positioning now though but ill figure that out. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Once the positioning was right i also needed to set the hidden attribute to !important in css. When i did this, the refresh came back, really wierd.

[hidden] {
 display: none !important;
}

Comment: I think it's a browser problem with `<object>`. Could be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995699/why-are-svg-objects-always-drawn-later

Comment: Indeed it was! I used <img> tag and everything is working just fine now. Thanks for your help!